# calling javascript function on click of button in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a javascript function in jsp page like this:

```
function shutDownall(){
  alert(document.forms[0].Name.value);
  var app_nm=document.forms[0].Name.value;
  alert(app_nm);
  document.forms[0].action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller?eventName=shutDownall&appname=" +app_nm;
  document.forms[0].submit();
  return true;

}
```

and a button like this which calls javascript function:

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:shutDownall();">shutdown servers</button>
```

where the javascript function is calling a method declared in action class. And button calls the javascript function calling java method. But when i click the shutdown server button nothing happens, not able to debug it. please help.

Comment: cleared Temp files??

Comment: yes i cleared temp files

Comment: check web browser error console

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the script in separate page be sure that the script file is included in the head of the page , but if the script in the same page you have to put this script before that button.

Comment: i am using script in same page which script we should put before button?

Comment: this script put it in the head

function shutDownall(){
  alert(document.forms[0].Name.value);
  var app_nm=document.forms[0].Name.value;
  alert(app_nm);
  document.forms[0].action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller?eventName=shutDownall&appname=" +app_nm;
  document.forms[0].submit();
  return true;

}

and the button but it like this 

<button type="button" onclick="shutDownall();">shutdown servers</button>